# why steps_per_epoch is causing memory error

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Assign any integer value  to steps per epoch is causing RAM over load

tried integer values and None.
None is basically 1, but it only works with None

```
results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=2, epochs=200,shuffle=False,steps_per_epoch=20,callbacks=[es,cs])
```

this is the error when integer value is assigned:

> InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.      [[{{node
>   _arg_input_1_0_0}}]]   [[{{node metrics/acc/div_no_nan}}]]

Comment: why are you using steps per epoch at all in fit? Also the error you say is not a memory error.